# How to find the smallest digit in a number and its position in a vector in C?

Tags: c, digits

Can someone please help me ? I need to put the number's digits into a vector, find the smallest digit among them, and print it along with its position in the vector.

```
    int main()
    {
        int n,i=0,v[100],Min=9,Position;
        scanf("%d",&n);
        while(n!=0)
        {
            v[i]=n%10;
            if(v[i]<Min)
            {
                Min=v[i];
                Position=i;
            }
            i++;
            n=n/10;

        }
        printf("%d, %d", Min, Position);
        printf("\n");
    }
```

input: 1234
output: 1, 3 <----  there is the problem, i can find the minimum digit but i can't get to show its position. instead of 0 it is 3, it counts from reverse input:2314
output: 1, 1 <-- should have been 1,2

Edit: Thank you "nicomp" now the final code looks like this.

```
int main()
{
     {
        int n,m,i,v[100],Lenght=0,Min=9,Position;
        scanf("%d",&n);
        m=n;
        while(m!=0)
        {
            m=m/10;
            Lenght++;
        }
        i=(Lenght-1);
        while(n!=0)
        {
            v[i]=n%10;
            if(v[i]<Min)
            {
                Min=v[i];
                Position=i;
            }
            i--;
            n=n/10;

        }
        printf("%d, %d", Min, Position);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: The mod operation pulls off the least significant digit first but the indexing starts from 0, the most significant digit. You need to reverse your indexing:
i = (length of n) - 1
then decrement i in the body of the loop.

Comment: @JohnnySmith88 You don't need one more loop to find the length of `n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you go for input `1234` (your code) starts with `4` and the position becomes `0` initially and later by the time you reach to digit `1` the positions is incremented to `3` - the better approach is to read the numbers from **1** to **4**  which can be done recursively, here is the code for doing that:

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 int vector[100];
 int i;
 int position;
 int Min=9;

 void locate(int num)
 {
     if(num>0)
     {
          locate(num/10);
          vector[i]=num%10;
          if(vector[i]<Min)
          {
               position = i+1;
               Min=vector[i];
          }
          ++i;
     }
 }

 int main()
 {
     int n;
     scanf("%d",&n);
     if(n<0)
         n=-n;
     locate(n);

     printf("Position %d  Min %d\n",position, Min);
     return n;
}
```

NOTE: When input is `1234` it shows the minimum digit's position as `1` instead as `0` as we need not to to read it as an array position but actual position.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to find length of `n` with additional loop.
You can just subtract the  `position` from `i`  as below, since `i` will be holding the length of `n`.

```
        int main()
        {
            int n,i=0,v[100],Min=9,Position=0;
            scanf("%d",&n);
            while(n!=0)
            {
                v[i]=n%10;
                if(v[i]<Min)
                {
                    Min=v[i];
                    Position=i;
                }
                i++;
                n=n/10;

            }
            printf("%d, %d", Min, (i - Position-1)); //<-----Here
           printf("\n");
        }
```